# Detecting app version in wso2emm

Tags: java, server, wso2-iot

In working with wso2emm, I've noticed a particular behavior that we'd like to change on our end.  This is that when you issue a deploy to a set of devices, the server will send one json message informing the client of a new update to their software, and if anything goes wrong in the process of downloading the update, the json message is lost.

I've saved this on the client end so that we can catch errors and retry and resume downloads.  My question is, since I'm unfamiliar with a lot of web development, where would one look to modify the logic for sending out messages to mobile clients?

Answer (score 1):

If your are using LOCAL notification for android, server add the message of update/install software in an API.

When android pull from server, device read that message and marked it as read into database status. Then server remove that message from API queue.
If your are using LOCAL notification for android, you can take any of these approach to find out what really happening.


Approach 1:(little bit manually)

```
Change android side code for sending version of device apps into server and change server side code to display app version in deivce tab UI.
Then cross check that your app have latest version or backdated version. If it have backdated version, then send update to that device/s.
```

Approach 2:

```
Do not mark as read this update message when 1st read this by device from API message queue.
Update read status after successfully update/install new version.
```